# Clone in builder Derived Classes

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class Compte, and CompteCarnet which derives from Compte:

```
public abstract class Compte
{
    protected int numCompte;
    protected DateTime dateCompte;
    protected float soldeCompte;
    protected Client propCompte;
}
```

and on the other class i do that :

```
class CompteCarnet : Compte
{
    private float tauxInteret;
    //Constructeur by copy 
    public CompteCarnet(CompteCarnet ca) 
    {
        this.tauxInteret = ca.tauxInteret;
    }
}
```

if this constructeur is correct 
Thanks in advance

Comment: **No**.Base class does not have any `constructor` which accepts the parameter of type `CompteCarnet`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a (copy) constructor for `Compte` which takes a `Compte` parameter and then fills each of its own values with the values from the parameter.

```
public abstract class Compte
{
  protected int numCompte;
  protected DateTime dateCompte;
  protected float soldeCompte;
  protected Client propCompte;

  // constructors of abstract classes are always protected, because abstract class can't be instantiated themselves and their constructors are only usable for sub-classes
  protected Compte(Compte compte)
  {
    numCompte = compte.numCompte;
    dateCompte = compte.dateCompte;
    soldeCompte = compte.soldeCompte;
    propCompte = compte.propCompte;
  }
}
```

`CompteCarnet` can be left as is, because it already has a proper copy constructor.

## Possible copy-by-reference issue with Client propCompte

Please note that if `Client` is a class doing it the way like above copies the reference. This means if you have `CompteCarnet c1` and do `var c2 = new CompteCarnet(c1);` c1 and c2 will have the exact same `propCompte` objects and every change you make on the contents of `c1.propCompte` will be reflected in `c2.propCompte`. If you don't want this `Client` also needs a copy constructor and the line

```
propCompte = compte.propCompte;
```

should be changed to

```
propCompte = new Client(compte.propCompte);
```

## Code style

That aside, a good style is to use properties instead of fields, which offer several advantages along the road. Also your fields/properties should probably be public, otherwise you can't access them outside of `Compte` or derivations of it like `CompteCarnet`. A minor nitpick is that repeating compte seems redundant, because they are from a class called compte and thus by definition are only related to compte.

In total, a better style would be:

```
public abstract class Compte
{
  public int Num { get; set; } // an auto-property
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public float Solde { get; set; }
  public Client Prop { get; set; }

  protected Compte(Compte compte)
  {
    Num = compte.Num;
    Date = compte.Date;
    Solde = compte.Solde;
    Prop = compte.Prop;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your constructor cannot delegate to the constructor in the base class, because the base class doesn't have a constructor (that accepts that type).

It seems you're trying to implement a copy constructor.
What you can do is the following:

```
class CompteCarnet: Compte {
    private float tauxInteret;

    public CompteCarnet(Compte ca) {
        if (ca is CompteCarnet derived)
            this.tauxInteret = derived.tauxInteret;
        numCompte = ca.numCompte;
        dateCompte = ca.dateCompte;
        soldeCompte = ca.soldeCompte;
        propCompte = ca.propCompte;

    }
}
```

A tip from me would be keep your source code in English. 
That follows most guidelines you'll find and it means everyone can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I can use that public CompteCarnet(CompteCarnet ca) : base(ca)
        {
            this.tauxInteret = ca.tauxInteret;

        }